# Upload large files to AWS s3 using express js synchrounsly

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-s3

Currently i am using `putObject` to upload the large file to AWS s3 with REST api call.

```
 var params ={               
     Bucket:'lambdacushbu',    
     Key:req.files.image.name, 
     Body:req.files.image.data 
 }                             
  s3.putObject(params,function(err, data) {                      
      if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred      
      else     {                                                      
          console.timeEnd('Uploadtime');                              
          console.log("uploaded",data);                               
          res.json({                                                  
              'status':'Uploaded',                                    
              'url':data.Location                                     
          });                                                         
      }           // successful response                              
  });
```

But its looks like asynchronous i want the above in synchronous mode also a timeout is occurred  but the file is being uploaded to the AWS s3.

So how can i increase the timeout value?? tried with `connect-timeout` package

```
app.use(timeout('600000'));
```

But it dosen't worked

Comment: Try the multer-s3 library

Comment: But multer is async??

Answer (score 1):

Try using `upload` function instead of `putObject`. That should solve your timeout problem.

Here is a documentation for that function: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#upload-property

Synchronous call will definitely lower your app's performance. Can you provide me more details about your problem so we can find an async solution?

EDIT:
Here is how you should return response in your controller:

```
router.post('/your-route',
  //additional middlewares
  function(req, res, next) {
     var params = {               
      Bucket:'lambdacushbu',    
      Key:req.files.image.name, 
      Body:req.files.image.data 
      }                             
      s3.upload(params,function(err, data) {                      
        if (err) { res.json(err); }      
        else {                                                        
           res.json({                                                  
          'status':'Uploaded',                                    
          'url':data.Location                                     
       }
      });                                             
  }
);
```

And make sure you don't call `res.json()` or `res.send()` anywhere else in this route

Comment: Upload is initiated via REST api call i(From mobile)and its asynchronous.But  the rest api is already emited the respnse. so how can i know the upload is finished or not in client side

Comment: You should return response to client after the upload on S3 is finished.
I'll modify my answer and provide you a code example

Comment: This approach is really good. But when I see the performance, AWS S3 command line uploads a 3gb file in 3 mins, whereas this command does the same thing in 15 minutes. Is there a way to speed up?